# android layout with visibility GONE

Tags: android, view, show-hide

Four views are using same xml. I want to show a linear layout for `view 1` only.
I put `android:visibility="gone"` in xml. And then I am doing the following for `view 1`-

```
LinearLayout layone= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layone);

layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But that doesn't set the visibility to visible.

Isn't it possible to show the view once its declared `GONE` in xml ?

I don't want to converse the logic by just doing,

```
layone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

in each of the three views except view 1.

Ideas or comments?

UPDATE:

My xml -

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/layone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Previous Page"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"          
            android:tag="PrevEntries"     
            android:id="@+id/laytwo"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@layout/roundedtext"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/laythree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Previous Page"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See my update with xml. I don't want to show this whole one by default. I only want it to be shown in my view 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done by having it like that:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_detail, container, false);
TextView tp1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tp1);
LinearLayout layone= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layone);
tp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It would help folks out if you should accept this answer so your question will display as resolved.  Cheers!

Answer (score 30):

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/layone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Previous Page"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

layone is a TextView.
You got your id wrong.

```
LinearLayout layone= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.laytwo);// change id here

layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

should do the job.

or change like this to show the TextView:

```
TextView layone= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layone);

    layone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: yes its ok, I want the whole to be not shown including text view.

Comment: So why are you referring to TextView with LinearLayout? Shouldnt work.

Comment: textview is above the linear layout and it is separate heading.

Comment: I know, but the way you are referring to TextView is wrong. See my edit.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Its correct. I just changed it here just as an example.

Comment: It was view 2 actually. Now I am getting null pointer exception at line `TextView laytwo= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.laytwo);
`

Comment: Finally, I got that visible. In `view.findViewById`, the view was null. I placed view first and then my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activity_register_header"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Try this piece of code..For me this code worked..

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Style way to do this more simple (example):

```java
    isVisible = false
```

Complete example:

```java
    if (some_data_array.details == null){
                holder.view.some_data_array.isVisible = false}
```

Answer (score 0):

**put this attribute in your xml view for Gone**

android:visibility="gone"

**put this attribute in your xml view for Show**

android:visibility="visible"

**Example**

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/futura_medium_bt"
            android:text="•Unlock all graphics"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
```