# How can Hide/Show some parts of my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys I wanna hide and show elements on my android app's layout. I did like in other solved questions here have been solved but it doesn't work :/ I leave you my code:

```
[...]
[...]
case 3:
            int numero_info=0;
            tvnomeditta.setText(Dati_souvenir[indice_riga][0]);
            tvindirizzoditta.setText(Dati_souvenir[indice_riga][1]);



            if (Dati_souvenir[indice_riga][3].equals(""))
            {
                v.findViewById(R.id.email_icon).isShown();
            }else{
                numero_info++;
                //tvindemail.setText(Dati_souvenir[indice_riga][3]);
            }

            if (Dati_souvenir[indice_riga][4].equals(""))
            {
                tvdescrizione.setText("Descrizione non trovata");
            }else{
                numero_info++;
                tvdescrizione.setText(Dati_souvenir[indice_riga][4]);
            }

            if (numero_info <=0)
            {
                v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        }
        [...]
        [...]
```

Thank you so much for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide it -

```
v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

show it again with -

```
v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or `numero_info <=0` is never `= true`

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure that `numero_info` is less or equal to `0`???

Comment: yes I'm sure, numero_info is not the problem

Comment: Then debug your code dude. Add Logs to your code. Add one in that `if (numero_info <=0)` statement if it really goes in that statement

Comment: I've already debug my code and numero_info is ok. I try also to set visible from java always in every condition to see if the visibility change and it doesn't change. If I set android:visibility="gone" in my linear layout I want to hide and show nothing happens when from my code I set v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in any cases

Comment: what is that `v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar)`? Why you do like that? What element is that `link_bar`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62656/discussion-between-pierpaolo-ercoli-and-martynas).

Comment: Why you extended Application in this class? Try with Activity

Comment: Solved, I update my solution :D

Comment: Great! :) wish you best luck in coding ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, best luck you too :D

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to show/hide views from the layout.

You have correctly used setVisibility() method but FYI there are 3 attributes you can use with it:

- View.VISIBLE - which makes item visible and stays there in layout
- View.INVISIBLE - which makes item invisible but stays there in layout
- View.GONE - whic makes item invisible and remove it's presence/space from layout.

So if you would want to complete hide the view then use GONE otherwise INVISIBLE.

Comment: first of all, thanks for answer. I'm new on android and I have some difficulties not with java but with xml. I wanna hide and show R.id.links_bar that is a LinearLayout. I try also with LinearLayout.GONE instead of View.GONE but nothing happens :/

Comment: does it work even if the item I want to hide is a Layout and not a button for example?

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli so you want to show/hide views inside XML layout itself? or at run time, I mean through code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option GONE instead of INVISIBLE.

A good option is to define it in XML as GONE and when you need it make it visible.

```
           <ListView
            android:id="@+id/links_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: but, if I define android:visibility="gone" the element in my layout isn't always gone? I wanna do it, only in some occasion. The real example is: if a place on the map have the telephone number I will show the telephone's icon, if the place don't have a telephone number I won't show the icon..

Comment: No. It means that your item doesn't take any space for layout purposes.You can make it visible again.

Comment: Here is an example of mine

Comment: Ok but your example doesn't work. I set visibility as gone in my layout and then from java I set visible, but nothing happen. Anyway I have another question for you. Is it possible that the problem is that the "item" I wanna hide/unhide is a LinearLayout?

Comment: No replied you at a post with my code to see how it works.
I have a RelativeLayout set as GONE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of mine I use for animating.

Java

```
    if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
        mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    }
```

XML

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/member_name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/hiddenlay"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desctv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Descr"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/kind"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kind "
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: In my case links_bar is a LinearLayout. But I don't think that there is any difference in this argument between Linear and Relative. Anyway, what is mAnimatedView ??

Comment: It's a View like the name says

Comment: Take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16166777/3347882

Comment: I solved now I update my solution, thanks to you too!